# Only one instance of object from ListIterator moves

Tags: java, list, arraylist, listiterator

I am working on a game project. So far so good, but i just stuck on ome basic thing and i cant find a solution and make it work properly. I decided to come here and ask you ppl of suggestions.

PROBLEM:
First, I had 2 levels with one bot in each of them. Later i noticed, that only the bot in the first level updates its behavior. If i only load the next level, the bots update method is not called and i dotn know why. 
I printed the ListIterator in to the console and the bot is there. But when i iterate trough the list in the main update method it seem it doesnt call the objects update method in it. I can still move with player and take diamonds from the map which both of them are also the part of the list so those methods are called. I can provide you with some smaller code blocks if you need to get some info on some specific things if i have them or not, just leave it in the comment. Here are some major blocks which in my opinion arent working proper.
If only the bot in the first level moves, i made another 4 bots to it. Only the first instance of Bot moves. All other items of the same class do nothing.

0.Declaration:

```
private ArrayList<AbstractObject> supp = new ArrayList<AbstractObject>();
private ListIterator<AbstractObject> objects=supp.listIterator();
```

1.Main update method:

```
public void update() {
    resetList(); //sets the cursor at begining
    if(menu.getChoice()==-1){
        menu.update();
    }
    else if(menu.getChoice()==2)
        System.exit(0);
    else if(menu.getChoice()==0){
        if(currentLevel>lvlm.getLevel() || currentLevel<lvlm.getLevel()){
            clearList(); //remove all items in the list
            init(lvlm.getLevelPath());
            currentLevel=lvlm.getLevel(); 

        }       
        while(objects.hasNext()){
                objects.next().update();      //calls all updates from each object in the list          
            }         
    }
}
```

2. Update method in the Bot Class:

   ```
   public void update() {         
   movingCount++;
   switch(getFacing()){
       case 2:
           moved=true;
           setFacing(2);
           setVectorX(-0.5);
           break;
       case 3:
           moved=true;
           setFacing(3);
           setVectorX(0.5);
           break;
       case 0:
       case 1:
           setVectorX(0);
           moved=false;
   }
   if(movingCount>=200){
       setFacing(randInt(0,3));
       movingCount=0;
   }
   moveOnX(); //updates pos
   moveOnY(); //updates pos
   getAnimationL().runAnimation();
   getAnimationR().runAnimation();
   ```

   }

EDIT_1:
Ok so the bots only in the first line in the file move.

LEVEL 1
P-player
B-bots
D-diamonds
1-walls

```
1111111    B   B
1P  D 1
11111 1
1F    1  B
1111111

B   B   B
```

Any ideas why only first line bots move? Other line objects works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterators only work once. You seem to be initialising the iterator once and then expecting it to work each time `update` is called.

Three options:

1. (Bad) reinitialise the iterator in update:

   `objects = supp.iterator();`
2. (Better) don't use an iterator; use a for loop:

   `for (AbstractObject obj: supp) {
       obj.update();
   }`
3. (Best) use a stream:

   `supp.stream().forEach(AbstractObject::update);`

If the update could potentially remove an item then your best option is to remove them after you've processed the list. For example, create a boolean method in `AbstractObject` called `shouldBeRemoved`. Then you can use the following:

```
supp.removeIf(AbstractObject::shouldBeRemoved);
```

After you have used one of the three methods above to process the list.

Comment: 1. The initialization is an empty arraylist because i am adding items directly in the listiterator with objects.add(). If i only initialized listiterator it throw an error exception. 2.I used that before, but with that enhanced loop i cant remove items from the list. For an example when I take the diamond it should disapears from the world. (The render draws all objects from the list.) 3.I havent tried that out, but when i do ill let to knwo how that worked out.

Comment: To the 1. I tried to add items to teh arraylist and than initialise objects=supp.iterator(), but the reinitialisation of the changed list (with out the items that should remove) thrown an exception.

Comment: I'll add a comment on removing items: in general you are better off removing 'used' items after you've processed the entire list.